# Consulta SQL en MySQL entre 3 tablas sum y count

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql

Tengo 3 tablas.
Una es `clientes`, otra `fotocopias` y `recargas_saldo`, relacionadas por `id_cliente` que es clave primaria en `clientes` y `foránea` en las demás.

Necesito sacar lo siguiente:

1.-`Nombre, apellidos` de la tabla `clientes`.

2.- La suma de todas las copias hechas por el cliente que se encuentran en `cantidad` de la tabla `fotocopias`.

3.- La suma de todas las recargas realizadas por el cliente que se encuentran en `cantidad_recargada` de la tabla `recargas_saldo`.

El problema es que si pongo `sum` y `count` me salen valores rarísimos y si no lo pongo veo que se me duplican los campos...
He probado con varias sentencias y nada...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
  `id_cliente` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `dni` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `saldo` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_alta` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `fotocopias` (
  `id_fotocopia` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_cliente` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_fotocopia` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_copias` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `fotocopias_saldo` (
  `id_registro` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_cliente` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_cliente` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido_cliente` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `saldo_old` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saldo_new` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_reg` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

Indices de la tabla `clientes`
--

ALTER TABLE `clientes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_cliente`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `fotocopias`
--
ALTER TABLE `fotocopias`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_fotocopia`),
  ADD KEY `id_cliente` (`id_cliente`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `recarga_saldo`
--
ALTER TABLE `recarga_saldo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_recarga`),
  ADD KEY `id_cliente` (`id_cliente`);
```

He probado:

```
select `clientes`.`nombre` AS `nombre`,`clientes`.`apellidos` AS `apellidos`,sum(`fotocopias`.`cantidad`) AS `total_copias`,count(`recarga_saldo`.`id_cliente`) AS `recargas`,sum(`recarga_saldo`.`cantidad_recargada`) AS `total_recargado` from ((`clientes` join `fotocopias`) join `recarga_saldo`) where ((`clientes`.`id_cliente` = `fotocopias`.`id_cliente`) = `recarga_saldo`.`id_cliente`) group by `clientes`.`id_cliente` ;
```

Y:

```
SELECT clientes.nombre, clientes.apellidos, sum(fotocopias.cantidad), count(recarga_saldo.id_cliente), sum(recarga_saldo.cantidad_recargada 
FROM CLIENTES
WHERE 
clientes.id_cliente = recargas_saldo.id_cliente = fotocopias.id_cliente
GROUP BY clientes.id_cliente
```

Pero no lo suma bien o no coge los valores bien, la verdad es que estoy bastante oxidado... :(

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para que puedas recibir una mejor ayuda ten la amabilidad de [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/205373/edit) aportando la siguiente información: - estructura de las tablas (puedes compartir el texto de los `CREATE TABLE`); - última consulta que estás usando (esa que dices que arroja valores rarísimos); - ejemplo mínimo de resultados deseados... Da preferencia a texto en vez de imágenes, pues es más fácil de leer y se puede reutilizar para hacer pruebas. Gracias.

Comment: Sería bueno que copies la consulta que estas realizando, ya que no se ve como estas agrupando los campos para utilizar **sum** y **count**

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo uniendo las tablas con `JOIN` y al mismo tiempo agrupando por clientes con `GROUP BY`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    c.nombre,
    c.apellidos, 
    SUM(f.cantidad) copias,
    SUM(r.cantidad_recargada) recargas
FROM clientes c
INNER JOIN fotocopias    f ON c.id_cliente = f.id_cliente
INNER JOIN recarga_saldo r ON c.id_cliente = r.id_cliente
GROUP BY c.id_cliente;
```

**Notas:**

- A veces las consultas no arrojan los datos esperados porque realmente hay error en los mismos datos
- En tus `CREATE TABLE`  se puede apreciar que no has creado llaves foráneas en las tablas, lo cual afectará la integridad y el rendimiento de las mismas. Deberías crear llaves foráneas
- No se entiende qué pinta la tabla `fotocopias_saldo`. Parece una tabla que maneja datos redundantes
- Es probable que la consulta haya que *estandarizarla* con respecto a las columnas `nombre` y `apellidos`. Lo puedes hacer poniéndolas **juntas** en una función de agregación como `GROUP_CONCAT`  o **separadas** con una función como `MAX` o `MIN`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. La base de datos la había hecho mi compañero, es para un proyecto pequeño... al final opté por borrar todo y volver a crearla, poniendo las claves foráneas y quitando los campos redundantes. El problema es que aún así la consulta duplicaba algunos valores o eran incorrectos, al final conseguí hacerlo con 3 subconsultas dentro de una consulta, como dijo el chico de abajo e igualando las claves foráneas de las otras dos tablas con la clave de clientes... si igualaba los 3 duplicaba algunos valores.

Comment: @Alex si las relaciones entre tablas son correctas y los datos son correctos debería funcionar también con `JOIN` y `GROUP BY`. Es la forma normal en que se suelen realizar este tipo de consultas.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer con subconsultas separadas (probablemente no sea la forma mas óptima)

La primera subconsulta traera los datos de las copias

```
SELECT id_cliente, sum(cantidad) FROM TABLA_FOTOCOPIAS GROUP BY id_cliente
```

La segunda consulta hara lo propio de las recargas

```
SELECT id_cliente sum(cantidad_recargada) FROM TABLA_RECARGAS_SALDO GROUP BY id_cliente
```

Ahora lo que tenemos que hacer es unir las subconsultas en otra consulta.

```
SELECT T1.id_cliente, T1.fotocopias, T2.recargas 
FROM 
    (SELECT id_cliente, sum(cantidad) as fotocopias FROM TABLA_FOTOCOPIAS GROUP BY id_cliente) AS T1, 
    (SELECT id_cliente sum(cantidad_recargada) as recargas FROM TABLA_RECARGAS_SALDO GROUP BY id_cliente) AS T2
WHERE T1.id_cliente = T2.id_cliente;
```

Comment: He probado y nada... me sale: #1054 - La columna 'T1.clientes' en field list es desconocida

Comment: Has copiado erroneamente. Fijate que en mi query no existe nada llamado T1.clientes.

Comment: Acabé editando tu consulta, añadiendo T3 y algunos datos más e igualando los codigos T1 con T2 y T3 con T1 y todo correcto. Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

intenta lo siguiente (generar una subconsulta en la consulta a tu tabla CLIENTES, en la que cada subconsulta busca la suma de los datos en fotocopias y en recargas)...
Con eso obtendras toda tu lista de clientes, y valores en 0 si no han hecho fotocopias (o recargas), o el valor total de los mismos.
Si te interesa puedes generar una VISTA en la Base de Datos para tener siempre lso datos a tu disposicion sin tener que calcularlos (solo haciendo select * from NOMBRE_DE_LA_VISTA)

```
SELECT  c.nombre,
c.apellidos, 
(select SUM(f.cantidad) from fotocopias f where c.id_cliente = f.id_cliente) copias,
(select SUM(r.cantidad_recargada) from recargas r where c.id_cliente = r.id_cliente) recargas FROM clientes c
```

Comment: por favor revisa [answer] y agrega una explicación